# Cast iron clawfoot tub diverter faucet riser stem question: what is this called?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have a clawfoot tub faucet where the "stem" that leads to the shower part is angled at less than 90 degrees because back of the tub is angled greater than 90 degrees from the floor. Most of the replacement faucets I have found online have a 90 degree angle for the "stem", but for some I see that the angle is acute -- unfortunately nothing from the respective descriptions/specifications seems to distinguish a 90 degree on from an acute angled one.

- What is the name of the thing I'm calling a "stem" and/or what term(s) can I use to find a replacement that is so angled?
- Is the difference implicit in the classifications "cast iron only" and "acrylic only"?

[image]

I wasn't able to get a great angle (no pun intended) on the picture, but the "stem" is the part pointing down in this picture, looking almost like a spigot itself but for the threads around the opening. I've tried to highlight it with a red line.

---

*UPDATE*

I have still been unable to find a replacement. Sign of the Crab says they have never seen anything like it. It appears to be an Elizabethan Classics model, which afaict is a Home Depot exclusive brand. Home Depot says they know nothing about it. Trips to the top plumbing/building supply shops and salvage yards have left me no closer to finding a replacement.

Luckily I happened upon a catalog that had tons of pictures of diverter valves and identified the Kingston Brass model that appears to be the one that failed on this unit, so I'm just going to replace that and hope nothing else happens to the faucet.

Comment: I ordered a replacement for both an acrylic tub and a cast iron tub, but both have the "stem" with a 90 degree angle.

Comment: This might require you to dig up some plumbing fixture manufactures who specialize in antique hardware. I would call them (email is easy to ignore) and speak with rep who you can send your marked picture to. Curious, I did a little leg work myself and found a company called Strom Plumbing who manufacture both the tubs and the plumbing hardware. Have a look at this page from their catalog which appears to show a faucet with shower stem on a sloped tub: http://reader.mediawiremobile.com/SIGNOFTHECRAB/issues/103717/viewer?page=23

Comment: is the picture upside down?

Comment: Yes @jsotola, it is upside down in that picture -- that is the shower stem pointing downwards.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vintagetub.com/bathroom/tub-faucets/tub-wall-mounted-faucets/randolph-morris-clawfoot-tub-faucet-with-handshower-and-porcelain-lever-handles-rm155bn-s.html
http://www.vintagetub.com/bathroom/tub-faucets/strom-plumbing-tub-faucet-with-diverter-for-riser-connection-p0006c-s.html
http://www.clawfootalley.com/handshower3.html

It is your Diverter valve, and the "neck" is your male (IPS?) shower riser interface.

Out of curiosity, if this valve is supposed to mount to a slanted wall of a tub, you might be able to find some hardware parts to allow you to adapt the "standard 90" units you are finding to mount to the tub with a tapered/slanted washer type of hardware to work with the 90.

Also, you could use an intermediate riser or custom  riser with a bend in it to meet your shower head (assuming you aren't on board with using flex tubing).

From what I read, it does seem like identifying the current faucet make is a good approach since apparently there is no standard defined for what angle the tub manufacturer used, so you will have to special order something, or order what you want and pay a shop to customize it to your needs.

Comment: I had the same problem once with a clawfoot tub faucet from Strom Plumbing (they were of no help whatsoever), I sort of solved it with a double set of "spherical leveling washers" which allowed me to install the faucet in the tub wall at an angle that left the shower riser pretty much vertical. Such can be had in stainless steel at https://www.mcmaster.com/products/leveling-washers/washer-type~spherical/